# Access VBA Displaying Unique Data in Text box

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007-2010 and I have 2 text boxes on a form.  What Im wanting to do is when a user inputs a name in `textbox1` (using `afterupdate`), such as "bob", I want to be able to display only the unique ages (no double ages) in `textbox2`. The names and ages are in a table called `data` laid out as so.

[Layout]

[image]

The `textbox2` would display `12, 64` or one below the other.

Sorry in advance if this is very simple to do, I am in the process of learning Access along with VBA

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit more than what youre looking for but try:

```
Dim ages(), name As String
Dim y, x, i As Integer

Dim rs As Recordset

name = Me.textbox1.Value

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from data Where name = '" & name & "'")



With rs

.MoveLast
x = .RecordCount
.MoveFirst

ReDim ages(1 To (x + 1))

Do Until rs.EOF
y = y + 1
If y = 1 Then

ages(y) = ![age]

Else

For i = 1 To y

If ages(y) = ages(i) And y <> i Then

ages(y) = "skip"
GoTo exiter

Else

'fine
ages(y) = ![age]
End If

Next i
End If
exiter:
.MoveNext

Loop

.Close
End With

y = 0

For y = 1 To x


If ages(y) <> "skip" Then

ages(x + 1) = ages(x + 1) & ages(y) & ","
End If

Next y


'feel free to change form msgbox to whatever form object you want

MsgBox " Entries in this List with the name " & name _
            & vbNewLine & ages(x + 1)
```

remove the vb new line and replace with "," and the msgbox with the textbox if you want

Comment: so Im trying to get your code to work as i look up all of this stuff and is it that you possibly left out an `End If` for one of the if statements in the Do Loop? I believe it goes after the `Next i` so I did that but it seems when i put a name in that has other ages, the msgbox at the end dosent get shown but if i put an name that has no ages or does not exist in the table, that msgbox pops up empty of ages of course.

Comment: Oops good catch. Should be an end if between `next i` and `exiter`

Comment: @RayceNeal the following changes should give you what you need:  `.MoveLast
x = .RecordCount
.MoveFirst `

and also

` If ages(y) = ages(i) And y <> i Then `